# Fixture Adapter filtering

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently writing an application relying on fixture data (REST API will follow) which I have some problems or misunderstandings with.

I'm displaying a lot of products in different categories and my index route e.g. should present only products containing a special flag.

```
TM.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return TM.Product.all().toArray().filter(function(item){
                        return item.get('featured') === 1;
                    });
}});
```

My problem: After loading the index route for the first time the model is empty. Switching to a different route and back to the index route loads the data as expected. I have the same issue with other filtering and no clue why this happens. It always works instantly without the filter - so my bindings have to be right.

I'm using the latest versions of ember (1.0.0-rc2) and ember-data (rev 12).

thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my problem. The .find() method is not returning full objects synchronously, they get populated asynchronously, even with the fixture adapter - which makes sense after all.

I guess the correct solution would be returning TM.Product.find({featured: 1}) as my model - which is not implemented within the fixture adapter. Rev. 11 of ember-data didn't give me a warning about that but rev 12 fortunately does.

Finally my wrong expectation of .find() on the fixture adapter returning results synchronously caused my problem.

Comment: Just a follow up, providing the model works now as expected but I had to "preload" all products by adding TM.Product.find() to the ApplicationController's init method. I assume this is an issue with the fixture adapter and I'll get back to this issue after connecting the REST backend.